# PHP Function to call mysql data on same page but with different ids

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have advertise table and it has ids

```
Advertise
-----------------------------------
ID    Title  Code       Position
-----------------------------------
1     Ad 1   Somecode   Left
2     Ad 2   Somecode   Right
3     Ad 3   Somecode   Bottom
-----------------------------------
```

My Display page has different functions so i cannot use while loop to break my other codes and then continue again. I even dont want to add three different queries to fetch each id. I have 3 fixed positions bottom, left and right so i want to add specific id to its specific div.

Comment: What are you asking? Do you not understand how to get the data from MySQL? Do you not understand how to display the right data on the page? It's not clear at all. Also what have you tried so far, and what problem did you have? This question is very vague.

Comment: And what do you want from us?

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far.

Comment: I have no idea what you're describing or asking.  Clearly there's a language barrier, but you're going to have to clarify.

Comment: I have solved my problem, thanks for your all of your time... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear to me what you are asking. But to give you a general idea as to how to pull data from a database, you can some of the following code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE Position = 'Left'";

$query = "SELECT ID FROM table_name WHERE Code = 'Somecode'";

$query = "SELECT Position FROM table_name WHERE ID = 3";
```

Please feel free to ask any follow up questions.